# Why can't i use UpdateStateByKey in my program?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, stateful

I have a variable **inputVector** : `DStream[(Int, BDM[Double])` where BDM is `Breeze Matrix`. I want to use `UpdateStateByKey` to it, but when i am trying to use it i get `Cannot resolve symbol UpdateStateByKey`.

I am a newbie in `Spark` but as far as i know you must only have `key-value` pairs in order to use it.

What am i missing?

My code is:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(3))
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
ssc.checkpoint("./checkpoints/")

var inputRdd = lines.map(x => x.split(","))

var arr = inputRdd.transform(x => x.groupBy(_ (1)).mapValues(x => x
                  .foldLeft(Array.ofDim[Double](C, T)) { (a, b) => {
                   var c = a
                   c(b(2).toInt)(findNextEmpty(a,b(2).toInt, T)) += b(3).toDouble
                   c  }}))

var inputVector = arr.transform(x => x.map(y=> (y._1.toInt, BDM(y._2.map(_.toArray):_*))))

var example = inputVector.updateStateByKey(somefunc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method's name is `updateStateByStream`, with a lowercase `u`, not `UpdateStateByStream`. Scala is case-sensitive.

Comment: That was my fault, i edited it. I have tried it with lowercase `u` too, i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `spark-streaming` library was not added fully in the dependencies of the project. So, i just added the `spark-streaming`.jar to the dependencies from `File->Project Structure->Modules`.